# 'dict' object has no attribute 'graph'

Tags: python, onnx, yolov5

When exported onnx model by using YOLOv5's export.py, I wanted to add some dictionary key-value pair information to the exported model. But failed.

```py
def export_onnx(model, im, file, opset, train, dynamic, simplify, config, config_path_info, prefix=colorstr('ONNX:')):
    # YOLOv5 ONNX export
    try:
        check_requirements(('onnx',))
        import onnx

        f = file.with_suffix('.onnx')

        torch.onnx.export(model, im, f, verbose=False, opset_version=opset,
                          training=torch.onnx.TrainingMode.TRAINING if train else torch.onnx.TrainingMode.EVAL,
                          do_constant_folding=not train,
                          input_names=['images'],
                          output_names=['output'],
                          dynamic_axes={'images': {0: 'batch', 2: 'height', 3: 'width'},  # shape(1,3,640,640)
                                        'output': {0: 'batch', 1: 'anchors'}  # shape(1,25200,85)
                                        } if dynamic else None)

        # Checks
        model_onnx = onnx.load(f)  # load onnx model
        onnx.checker.check_model(model_onnx)  # check onnx model

        # Simplify
        if simplify:
            try:
                check_requirements(('onnx-simplifier',))
                import onnxsim

                model_onnx, check = onnxsim.simplify(
                    model_onnx,
                    dynamic_input_shape=dynamic,
                    # input_shapes={'images': list(im.shape)} if dynamic else None
                    )
                assert check, 'assert check failed'
                onnx.save(model_onnx, f)
            except Exception as e:
                LOGGER.info(f'{prefix} simplifier failure: {e}')
        LOGGER.info(f'{prefix} export success, saved as {f} ({file_size(f):.1f} MB)')
        
        model_torch = torch.load('../model_with_info.pth')
        model_dict = {}
        for k, v in model_torch.items():
            if k == 'inference_engine':
                model_dict[k] = 'ONNX'
            elif k == 'model_weight':
                model_dict[k] = model_onnx
            else:
                model_dict[k] = v
        onnx.save(model_dict,  '../model_with_info.onnx')
        return f
    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.info(f'{prefix} export failure: {e}')
```

Error messages are following:

```
2022-07-18 07:53:07,743 - yolo.py[line:219] - INFO: Fusing layers... 
2022-07-18 07:53:07,977 - torch_utils.py[line:251] - INFO: Model Summary: 213 layers, 7015519 parameters, 0 gradients, 15.8 GFLOPs
2022-07-18 07:53:08,018 - export.py[line:547] - INFO:   PyTorch: starting from ../model_with_info.pt with output shape (1, 25200, 7) (14.4 MB)
2022-07-18 07:53:08,049 - export.py[line:75] - INFO:    ONNX: starting export with onnx 1.8.204...
2022-07-18 07:53:10,944 - export.py[line:156] - INFO: ONNX: export failure: 'dict' object has no attribute 'graph'
```

I think it's how to solve the problem of Dict loading Graph data. Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: Can you add the complete error message and traceback, please?

Comment: error messages are just "export.py[line:156] - INFO: ONNX: export failure: 'dict' object has no attribute 'graph' ".

Comment: Please, add the full error message and stack trace to the question.

Comment: sounds like torch.onnx.export contains a graph object instead of returning a dict, but since your code is incomplete it's impossible to say where your error is. Hopefully that helps you solve the issue for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load_state_dict.

```
model_torch.load_state_dict(torch.load('../model_with_info.pth', map_location=device))
```

Comment: I assume you mean instead of `model_torch.items()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this problem does not seem to be with the loading model. I think it's how to solve the problem of Dict loading Graph data.